# What kind of algorithm should I use to find similarities in a db?

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm

Let's say I have 1000 users for my app. I ask them 100 questions with answers just yes/no and I record those answers in a seperate table.

Now, I want to see people who has given the same answers to at least 20 questions.

What kind of algorithm should I follow in order to do this? What are the relevant keywords for googling?

P.S. I work in a WAMP environment.

Comment: How did you store the answers to these questions?

Comment: I have a db table called 'answers'. It has three columns; user_id, question_id and answer (which is yes or no).@Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join your answers table to itself, selecting answers which share the same `question_id` and `answer` but have a different `user_id`. Group the rows by both `user_id`s and use a `HAVING` clause to exclude those with less than 20 matching answers.

Example where you are looking for users similar to your user with `user_id` "1":

```
SELECT DISTINCT a2.user_id FROM answers a
INNER JOIN answers a2
        ON a.question_id = a2.question_id
       AND a.answer = a2.answer
       AND a.user_id != a2.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = 1
GROUP BY a.user_id, a2.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;
```

Technically you don't need to group by `a.user_id` in this case but I've left it there in case you want to modify the `WHERE` clause to return results for more than one `a.user_id`.